# Yandex Map в Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, mapkit

Я впервые села работать с MapKit под Android Studio. Пытаюсь подключиться, но мне почему то выдает ошибку. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где ошибка?

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.2' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir 
    repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://repo.spring.io/release"
    }
    maven {
        url "https://repository.jboss.org/maven2"
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Покажите логи ошибки. Также не ясно зачем вам это: `version '7.1.2' apply false`

Comment: Без доп инфы тут нечего сказать. Ссылка на доку в помощь разве что: https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/mapkit/doc/android-quickstart/concepts/android/quickstart.html#quickstart__install